# Lambda Python psycopg mogrify is adding one more apostrophe after escape character

Tags: python, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I have a lambda function to read the RDS PostgreSQL table and insert records in the Redshift table.
The RDS table has a value with escape char (e.g. Abc's) in one of the rows.
python (using `psycopg2`) is reading value as  abc\'s (which is correct).
I am using mogrify to create insert query (for more than one row from RDS). The query generated is: `Insert into table_name (id, col1) values (1, 'abc\''s');`

The extra `'` (apostrophe) is causing insert query failure.

> - syntax error at 's. Redshift is considering 'abc' as a string and 's' extra value.

code snippet :

```
    query_rds_source : f'Select id, col1 from tbl1;'
    RDS_conn = psycopg2.connect(
            database= RDS_dbname, user= uname_PostgreSQL ,
            password=password_PostgreSQL, host=host_PostgreSQL, port=port_PostgreSQL
        )
        RDS_conn.autocommit = True
        RDS_cursor = RDS_conn.cursor()
        RDS_cursor.execute(query_rds_source)
    row_source = RDS_cursor.fetchall()
    args_str = ','.join(RDS_cursor.mogrify("(%s,%s)", x).decode('utf-8') for x in row_source)
    insert_query = f'Insert into public.{redshift_stg_ups_tbl} (id, col1) values {args_str}'
    #another connection and cursor for redshift. 
    Redshift_cursor.execute(insert_query)

Error : 
    [ERROR] SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "S"
LINE 1: 1,'Abc\''S'
```

Tried AsIs module but not helping.

Can anyone please advise how to resolve this?

Comment: You need to spend time in the `psycopg2` docs here [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) to learn the proper and safe way to build dynamic SQL. `args_str = ','.join(RDS_cursor.mogrify("(%s,%s)", x)...` and then `...execute(insert_query)` is double parsing the string which why you are ending up with doubled quotes. Don't do that.